# How to debug JavaScript that won't retrieve data from MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm following this tutorial: https://anmolkoul.wordpress.com/2015/06/05/interactive-data-visualization-using-d3-js-dc-js-nodejs-and-mongodb/

After getting through a few problems everything seems to be working but the page doesn't show the data from MongoDB. It looks like it's trying to connect but always ultimately fails.

I even put my Mongo collection on to mLab to see if it could connect to somewhere other than localhost. It does not.

I have a Server.js file

```
// modules =================================================
var express        = require('express');
var app            = express();
var mongoose       = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser     = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');

// configuration ===========================================

// config files
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080; // set our port
var db = require('./config/db');

// connect to our mongoDB database (commented out after you enter in your own credentials)
connectionsubject = mongoose.createConnection(db.urlSubjectViews);



// get all data/stuff of the body (POST) parameters
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // parse application/json 
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' })); // parse application/vnd.api+json as json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded

app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override')); // override with the X-HTTP-Method-Override header in the request. simulate DELETE/PUT
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users

// routes ==================================================
require('./app/routes')(app); // pass our application into our routes

// start app ===============================================
app.listen(port);   
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);           // shoutout to the user
exports = module.exports = app;                         // expose app
```

A db.js file for pointing at the database:

```
    module.exports = {
    urlSubjectViews: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/donorschoose',

}
```

a SubjectViews.js file to point at the data I need

```
// define our nerd model
// module.exports allows us to pass this to other files when it is called
module.exports = connectionsubject.model('', {}, 'projects');
```

And a Route.js file to set up a route for the JSON data

```
var Subjects = require('./models/SubjectViews');

module.exports = function(app) {

    // server routes ===========================================================
    // handle things like api calls
    // authentication routes    
    // sample api route
 app.get('/api/data', function(req, res) {
  // use mongoose to get all nerds in the database
  Subjects.find({}, {'_id': 0, 'school_state': 1, 'resource_type': 1, 'poverty_level': 1, 'date_posted': 1, 'total_donations': 1, 'funding_status': 1, 'grade_level': 1}, function(err, subjectDetails) {
   // if there is an error retrieving, send the error. 
       // nothing after res.send(err) will execute
   if (err) 
   res.send(err);
    res.json(subjectDetails); // return all nerds in JSON format
  });
 });





 // frontend routes =========================================================
 app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile('./public/index.html');
 });
}
```

This is my collection in Studio 3T:
[Mongo Collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgLqb.png)

I know it's pointing at the database because when I look at localhost:8080/api/data the page shows itself loading but timesout after a while. It only seems like it's me with this problem??

Comment: what versions of mongoose/mongodb server/node are you using?

Comment: Mongo Shell v3.4.9, Express 4.5.1, Mongoose 3.8.0, Node 8.6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more general problem in this case is that you're following a tutorial that's 3 years old, based on a package that doesn't work as advertised ( at least not anymore or not for me ).

```
opc: git clone https://github.com/anmolkoul/node-dc-mongo.git
Cloning into 'node-dc-mongo'...
remote: Counting objects: 930, done.
remote: Total 930 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 930
Receiving objects: 100% (930/930), 1.75 MiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (133/133), done.
opc: cd node-dc-mongo/
node-dc-mongo>: rm -rf node_modules/
node-dc-mongo>: npm install
npm WARN deprecated mongodb@1.4.38: Please upgrade to 2.2.19 or higher

> bson@0.2.22 install /Users/lineus/dev/opc/node-dc-mongo/node_modules/bson
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bson/ext/bson.o

> kerberos@0.0.11 install /Users/lineus/dev/opc/node-dc-mongo/node_modules/kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN starter-node-angular@1.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN starter-node-angular@1.0.1 No license field.

added 64 packages in 8.994s
node-dc-mongo>: node server.js 
{ Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/lineus/dev/opc/node-dc-mongo/node_modules/bson/ext/index.js:15:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
Magic happens on port 8080
^C
node-dc-mongo>:
```

So, it's going to take a bit of work to get it going.

Let's start by simplifying the problem space just a bit by creating a standalone file that mimics the Mongoose bits of your code so it will be easier to reason about. ( I'm using a newer version of Mongoose but the details are the same ).

```
'use strict'

const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/test')

const Model = conn.model('', {}, 'tests')

Model.find({}, (err, docs) => {
  if (err) { return console.error(err) }
  console.log(`there are ${docs.length} docs in this collection.`)
  return conn.close()
})
```

If we run this code, there is no output, and everything appears stuck.

```
49715319: node ./connect.js
^C
49715319:
```

The createConnection method returns a connection object that inherits from eventEmitter. In order to use the returned connection object successfully, we have to "listen" for the 'open' event.

We can change our file like so:

```
'use strict'

const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/test')

const Model = conn.model('', {}, 'tests')

conn.on('open', function (err) {
  if (err) { return console.error(err) }
  Model.find({}, (err, docs) => {
    if (err) { return console.error(err) }
    console.log(`there are ${docs.length} docs in this collection.`)
    return conn.close()
  })
})
```

The output becomes:

```
49715319: node ./connect.js
there are 1000 docs in this collection.
49715319:
```

**This would mean you should change your server.js file like so**:

```
// modules =================================================
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');

// configuration ===========================================

// config files
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080; // set our port
var db = require('./config/db');

// connect to our mongoDB database (commented out after you enter in your own credentials)
connectionsubject = mongoose.createConnection(db.urlSubjectViews);


connectionsubject.on('open', function (err) {
  if (err) { return console.error(err) }
  // get all data/stuff of the body (POST) parameters
  app.use(bodyParser.json()); // parse application/json
  app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' })); // parse application/vnd.api+json as json
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded

  app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override')); // override with the X-HTTP-Method-Override header in the request. simulate DELETE/PUT
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users

  // routes ==================================================
  require('./app/routes')(app); // pass our application into our routes

  // start app ===============================================
  app.listen(port);
  console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);           // shoutout to the user
  exports = module.exports = app;                         // expose app
})
```

This won't start the express app until Mongoose successfully connects to the server.

It will likely also still not work given the version of Mongoose you're using. If it still fails I would suggest installing the latest version of Mongoose or at least the latest version of Mongoose 4 at the time of this writing.

Just for the sake of completeness, this is how I generated the docs for this test collection ( using Mongoose 5 ):

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict'

const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const schema = new Schema({
  name: String
})

const Test = mongoose.model('test', schema)

const tests = []

for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  tests.push(new Test({ name: `testing${i}` }))
}

async function run () {
  await mongoose.connection.dropDatabase()
  let docs = await Test.create(tests)
  console.log(`added ${docs.length} docs to ${Test.modelName}`)
  return mongoose.connection.close()
}

run()
```

Comment: How would you recommend rewriting this in a more up to date version of Mongoose? I'm really stressed for time and just want this working haha, thank you for taking the time to help though I really appreciate it

Comment: just change the server.js file like I did in my comment above, do npm install mongoose@latest, and run it. If it gives you any errors feel free to jump on https://gitter.im/Automattic/mongoose and we can sort it out :)

Comment: I made the line right before the code for changing your server.js file bold above to make it easier to find. I know it was long answer, sorry :)

Comment: Thank you, I'm off to work now but I'll be back a bit later to try again

Comment: This is a great answer lineus, hope to see you here more in the future! Good work.

Comment: Thanks halfer! I appreciate it :)

Comment: I just got back and updated mongoose in the package and it works! Thank you SO MUCH!